# Manipulate JSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am developing a codeigniter application. I need the returned json data in this format.

```
 {
        options: [
    {id:"1",text:"test"},
    {id:"2",text:"kabita123"},
    {id:"3",text:"purnima"},
    {id:"4",text:"raju123"},
    {id:"5",text:"saad123"},
    {id:"12",text:"apf123"}
        ]
    }
```

However, when returning the data, I only have it in this format

```
[{"id":"1","text":"test"},
{"id":"2","text":"kabita123"},
{"id":"3","text":"purnima"},
{"id":"4","text":"raju123"},
{"id":"5","text":"saad123"},
{"id":"12","text":"apf123"}]
```

Where am I doing it wrong ? The code I am using to generate the json data is

```
        $users = $this->user_m->get_all();  
        $user_arr = [];
        $i=0;
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user_arr[$i] = new stdClass();
            $user_arr[$i]->id = $user->id;
            $user_arr[$i]->text = $user->username;
            $i++;
        }
       //add the header here
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $user_arr );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
echo json_encode( $user_arr );
```

to:

```
echo json_encode( array('options' => $user_arr) );
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You saved my day :) . It must have been a silly question. But I am new to JSON so was struggling with it for hours.  Thanks again.